# How can I add power plans to the battery notification area in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, battery

In previous versions of Windows it was possible to choose a power plan by left-clicking the battery icon and selecting the relevant power plan.

As far as i can tell in Windows 10, this is not possible but instead it requires a right-click, select 'Power Options' which opens a window in which a power plan can be selected. This adds an unnecessary additional step.

[image]

Is there a way in which I can add the power plans as a tab in the Windows 10 battery notification area shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10, there is no build-in setting to revert it back, you can try to use this opensource project: https://powerbuddy.codeplex.com/

It supports to show all Power plans in the Windows power tray icon:
[image]